# How do I edit iCloud files under Documents & Data?

Tags: icloud

I have an old game I used to play but I have lost my old save file. I remember exactly what I have (written everything down on an old sheet of paper) and would like to restore it manually by editing its entry under Documents & Data under iCloud. I would like to know how to access the files under this section and how to edit them.

Would it require macOS or could it be done through Windows?

Comment: That would heavily depend on what format the file was in. Plain text, binary of some sort, XML, JSON, etc. You will likely need an example to go off of. Once you have that you can examine the file to determine what format it is in. Perhaps a good question to ask the developer.

Comment: Where would be a good place to start to at least edit the local files? Is there a program I could use to access my app's data in order to read/write it?

Comment: macOS has several built-in text editors, Textedit is the simplest, but there is VI, Nano and other Unix-y text editors as well. BBEdit is a great text editor as well.